# Salesforce metadata API retrive field updates

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

how can i retrive all the field updates in a salesforce org. Is it possible with Package.xml

```
<types> <members>*</members> <name>Workflow</name> </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
```

I tried both with API version 55 and 39. But it does not retrieve the fieldupdate definition it does retrieve workflows but only with field update name not its complete metadata.

If not possible with MetaData API is there anything else i can retrieve it with, there is a legacy salesforce of with uses hundreds of field update, need to have it locally in order to perform analysis. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot retrieve `WorkflowFieldUpdate` using `<members>*</members>` tag. You would need to use below package.xml format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Objectname.Field_Update_Name</members>
        <members>Objectname2.Field_Update_Name</members>
        <members>Objectname3.Field_Update_Name</members>
        <members>Objectname4.Field_Update_Name</members>
        <name>WorkflowFieldUpdate</name>
    </types>
    <version>56.0</version>
</Package>
```

As a workaround you can use [Force.com Migration Tool Package Creator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forcecom-migration-tool-p/jjnhjeoeaiiifekieoddeenhoignfkhj?hl=en) chrome extension and copy generated package.xml using workbench.

[image]